# Failed asserting the HTTP status code is 200 not 500

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, functional-testing

I'm trying to functional test the HTTP status code for a certain request is `200` not `500`. I'm using Symfony2, and here's the code:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', "/");
    $this->assertEquals('Ibw\JobeetBundle\Controller\JobController::indexAction', $client->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller'));
    $this->assertEquals(200 , $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $this->assertEquals(0, $crawler->filter('.jobs td.position:contains("Expired")')->count());
}
```

And the result :

> 1) Ibw\JobeetBundle\Tests\Functional\JobControllerTest::testIndex
>   Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.

When I access the route "/" manually through the browser it works just fine.

So what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 500 error can be caused by anything in your case.

What you could do in such situation is to dump the content of the response and check the Symfony debugging message.

I usually use such code snippet for quick checking such errors directly in terminal:

```
if (!$response->isSuccessful()) {
    $block = $crawler->filter('div.text_exception > h1');
    if ($block->count()) {
        $error = $block->text();
    }
}
```

where `div.text_exception > h1` is the xpath from Symfony2 debug page to the message itself

Then just print the `$error`

Comment: Hmmm, but what is `div.text_exception > h1` ?

Comment: @RafaelAdel xpath to the message itself. Updated my answer

Comment: Hmm i've tried it, but i got nothing printed back. I think the `if($block->count())` returns false. Because i've placed `$this->assertEquals("dummy", $error)` inside that `if` statement.

Comment: Ok i've found it, It's `text-exception` NOT `text_exception`.

Comment: @RafaelAdel It might depend on the framework version

Comment: For Symfony4, the filter should look like " 'h1.exception-message' " : $block = $crawler->filter('h1.exception-message');

Answer (score 0):

You could also echo the html after the request to see what's in the response.

```
echo $crawler->html();
```