# Failed asserting the HTTP status is 200 not 500

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am having issues running phpunit tests on our symfony application.

I am using the following assertion code:

```
namespace Main\MyBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

       var_dump( $client->getInternalResponse());

        //checking home page availability
        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

    }
}
```

However I keep getting a failure as you can see from result below:

```
    mcp@mcp-buildbox:/var/www/my.app.com$ phpunit -c app src/Main/MyBundle
    PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

    Configuration read from /var/www/my.app.com/app/phpunit.xml.dist

    Fclass Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response#182 (3) {
      protected $content =>
      string(138299) "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>\n        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />\n        <title>    Undefined index: SERVER_PORT (500 Internal Server Error)\n</title>\n        <link href="/bundles/framework/css/structure.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />\n        <link href="/bundles/framework/css/body.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />\n            <link href="/bundles/framework"...
      protected $status =>
      int(500)
      protected $headers =>
      array(3) {
        'cache-control' =>
        array(1) {
          [0] =>
          string(8) "no-cache"
        }
        'date' =>
        array(1) {
          [0] =>
          string(29) "Thu, 08 May 2014 15:32:16 GMT"
        }
        'content-type' =>
        array(1) {
          [0] =>
          string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        }
      }
    }

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 22.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) Main\MyBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.

/var/www/my.app.com/src/Main/MyBundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:25

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Here is my framework settings in config.yml:

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
        http_port: 80
        https_port: 443
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: "%trusted_proxies%"
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~
    trusted_hosts:   ~
```

Also please note that when I do:

```
curl -I http://my.app.com
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I am also using PHP 5.4.9 and on an ubuntu machine. Can someone help? I looked on stack and see someone else had identical issue but the resolution is not clear to me and the answer is not really a solution:

[Failed asserting the HTTP status code is 200 not 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426364/failed-asserting-the-http-status-code-is-200-not-500)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed asserting the HTTP status code is 200 not 500](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426364/failed-asserting-the-http-status-code-is-200-not-500)

Comment: not a duplicate. Read the question fully to the end. I added the link at bottom myself. Please take the time to read fully rather then add close votes if applicable. The linked question that I added does not solve the issue.

Comment: OP is correct. This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: can you please add the contents of phpunit.xml.dist ?

Comment: I wish, people would read the error messages.. `Undefined index: SERVER_PORT (500 Internal Server Error)` you have an error in your homepage.

Comment: That was mentioned by the fact that OP did a CURL session that shows the app is running fine. I wish people would just answer the question if they know the answer and not make sarcastic comments that are not meaningful.

Comment: It seems that since phpunit runs on the command line that there is some difficulty with the CLI and the SERVER_PORT setting.

Comment: When you run as CLI, there is no server involved, so you cannot assume `$_SERVER` does contain anything. That's why you should not access that variable in the first place - frameworks do offer abstraction layers to make the code independent from such details. Or at least, check if the array index exists, and use a default value otherwise.

Comment: is there an answer for the Question?