# Trouble testing HTTP verbs with PHPUnit in Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

Before I get started, I'd like to say that I've already looked at [Failed asserting the HTTP status is 200 not 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546606/failed-asserting-the-http-status-is-200-not-500) as well as [Failed asserting the HTTP status code is 200 not 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426364/failed-asserting-the-http-status-code-is-200-not-500). Do not let the names fool you; they are 2 different posts. Both of these posts are older than 9 months and have no good answers.
I'm having some trouble testing routes. So, I made a new `Laravel 5` project on my Mac Mini running `OS X Yosemite 10.10.2`. I'm making an API. So, I started making the backend part of the API first. I decided that I wanted to use `PHPUnit` to implement TDD for this project. My version of `PHPUnit` is `4.0.20`. I'm running `PHP 5.5.14` and I'm using the server packaged with `Laravel` in the `artisan` command line tool.
Now, I started with making sure that I could just connect to the server. So, my first test looks like:

```
public function testGetMessagesResponse()
{
    $response = $this->call('GET', 'Messages');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

This passes just fine. However, when I moved on to the POST request, it failed. This is what my second test looks like:

```
public function testPostMessagesResponse()
{
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'Messages');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

This test fails. Here is what the output looks like:

```
1) MessagesTest::testPostMessagesResponse
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.
```

In my routes.php file, I do have this route registered:

```
Route::resource('Messages', 'MessagesController');
```

In my MessagesController, I have all the required methods:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MessagesController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return 'response';
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return 'response';
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        return 'response';
    }

    /**
    * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return 'response';
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        return 'response';
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        return 'response';
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        return 'response';
    }

}
```

So, for the time being, no matter the HTTP verb, I should get `'response'`. Now, I decided to verify the test with curl:

```
curl -X POST http://myapp.com/Messages
```

This returns the Laravel 'Oops!' page. So there is indeed *some* kind of server error, but I'm not sure what to look for. The application flow looks good, but it obviously is not working. Here is the stack trace from my Laravel log:

```
[timestamp] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php:2375
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/username/Sites/project/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(8858): App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#2 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(11990): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(8858): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(10696): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(8858): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#6 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(11696): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(8858): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(11645): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(8858): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(2411): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(8858): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(8849): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(1862): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 /Users/username/Sites/project/storage/framework/compiled.php(1852): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /Users/username/Sites/project/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /Users/username/Sites/project/server.php(21): require_once('/Users/username/Site...')
#18 {main}
```

I'm pretty new to Laravel and so I'm not sure how to really dig in and use the stack trace to figure out what is going wrong. I have also tried this without `Route::resource`, but this does not alleviate my situation. My GET still works just fine (`Route::get`), but my POST (`Route::post`) is still getting that same 500 error. The function encompassing line 2375 in .../compiled.php (from the exception thrown at the top of the stack trace) is generated by Laravel and looks like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request)) {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }
    throw new TokenMismatchException();
}
```

At that point, I tried to edit the POST test, since I wasn't actually sending any data. So here is my revised second test:

```
public function testPostMessagesResponse()
{
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'Messages', array("key" => "value"));

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

I get the same error message. I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see your problem in the first function of the call stack

```
#0 /Users/username/Sites/project/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
```

It looks like Laravel 5 is automatically checking a POST request for a CSFR token (cross site request forgery).  This would be something you'd create on your form in a brower based UI to help prevent cross site request forgeries.

Since a A CSFR token doesn't make sense for an API, you'll want to remove this Middleware.  It seems like the default setup of a Laravel 5 app gives you a Kernal class file

```
#File: app/Http/Kernel.php
<?php namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',

    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    ];

}
```

For your API only project, you can probably just remove the

```
'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
```

entry from the `$middlewares` property and you'll be good to go.  If you're going to create an application with a browser UI, you'll want to keep this Middleware in place, and then read up [on Middlewares](http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style) to see how you can use it on specific requests. (The short version?  Middlewares are a way to do things that happen on every HTTP request but don't impact your actual application code)

Answer (score 6):

@Alan Storm: you are completely right in what is happening. I posted this same question on Laracasts and the issue you are describing is mirrored there. However, to give credit where credit is due, I received a bit more elegant of a solution to the issue. So, I'm re-posting it here so that others have it if they have the same issue. From JarekTkaczyk at Laracasts:

> The thing is, that Laravel 5 runs VerifyCsrfToken middleware for each request, no exceptions. It verifies that the request is either read (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) or has valid token.
>
> In your case there is no valid token, so you get TokenMismatchException. Now, to get rid of the problem you can disable this verification for testing environment.
>
> Simply adjust app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php to this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ('testing' !== app()->environment())
    {
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

> Now, happy testing!

Comment: YMMV, but in general modifying a class that provides a middleware vs. modifying a class that provides your application configuration seems like a less stable change.  (although the problem seems to be Laravel including middleware classes as part of the `app` without a clear distinction between what should and shouldn't be user editable -- my development tradition would put the CSFR class as part of the framework)

Comment: I just got done reviewing middleware and I can see what you mean between separating configurations like the middleware that I declare in `Kernel.php` from the Laravel code base. For now, I have the second solution applied. However, I am going to add user authentication soon and so that will probably change soon.

Comment: For the reasons in the comment from @AlanStorm, I have changed the answer so others don't go digging in the 'wrong' place and so they can make the changes in the 'right' file.

Comment: For the Googlers -- another approach would be creating **your own** VerifyCsrfToken class that extends `Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken` and redefines the methods you need it to.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to offer an alternative solution to the two currently here. Both solutions are *circumventing* the CSRF middleware in place (either by disabling it or modifying the code behind it). I think for the legitimate cases where you would want CSRF protection and want to test, its better to modify the test than to modify the code to accommodate a non-representative test.

I also think that having a code block resembling this

```
if ('testing' !== app()->environment()) {
   // Path taken only when not testing
}
```

as in @beznez's own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369127/1852838), anywhere in your code is asking for sneaky bugs down the line. As far as possible, test code should take the same path as anyone/anything else interacting with the code.

Its not that difficult to actually have the CSRF token in the request, just like it would be present in a normal browser request. The only trick is you have to start a session and then add a `_token` key to your request with a value returned by `csrf_token()` (just like in the forms). So your modified test code would be:

```
public function testPostMessagesResponse()
{
    Session::start(); // Start a session        

    $response = $this->call(
        'POST', 'Messages', array("key" => "value", "_token" => csrf_token()));

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

This is elaborated on in this blog [post](http://davejustdave.com/2015/02/08/laravel-5-unit-testing-with-csrf-protection/).

Comment: That's a good point. I'm doing another project right now and I may implement the tests this way to try this method out. Adding another parameter is not a big deal and then I can get an accurate test. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Just checking in to say that I've implemented a test this way and I feel much better about what is actually being tested. Thanks very much for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm happy to hear you feel better about your tests now =).

Comment: As the author of the blog [post](http://davejustdave.com/2015/02/08/laravel-5-unit-testing-with-csrf-protection/) jeteon mentions above, I'll say that adding the CSRF token into my tests has worked out well. It certainly makes me feel more confident about the code I'm testing.

Comment: Wow, my tests were failing for no discernible reason. Luckily, I just stumbled across this page and it turns out the missing CSRF token was the issue. I too think this is answer is the most stable and scalable solution, but to simplify it and make it a bit more reusable, I added a static method to my top-level `TestCase` class that takes an array of parameters and adds the token if it doesn't already exist. Nice solution here though compared to the middleware "hacks".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware, it would be much better to just simulate a real user session without disabling anything.

You just need to start a new **`Session`** inside your test and then pass the `csrfToken` when testing csrf protected routes.

```
use Session;

...

public function testPostMessagesResponse()
{
    Session::start();
    $params = [
        'key'    => 'value',
        '_token' => csrf_token()
    ];

    $response = $this->call('POST', 'Messages', $params);

    $response->assertSuccessful();
}
```